# Group common ID's based on most and the least recent date

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to take the highest and the lowest date from two fields from my data and group them based on the ids. I noticed that my date fields got a string which is blocking the sort and restricting me from getting the right results.

my data set --df

| id | login | logout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/11/2020 | 03/23/2021 |
| 1 | 08/12/2020 | now |
| 1 | 01/10/2018 | now |
| 1 | 02/02/2021 | 02/03/2021 |
| 2 | 04/05/1990 | 03/22/2021 |
| 3 | 01/25/2010 | 02/22/2021 |
| 2 | 06/12/2015 | now |
| 4 | now | now |

what i'm getting:

| id | login | logout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/10/2018 | now |
| 2 | 04/05/1990 | now |
| 3 | 01/25/2010 | 02/22/2021 |
| 4 | now | now |

how i expect the output to be

| id | login | logout |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/10/2018 | 03/23/2021 |
| 2 | 04/05/1990 | 03/22/2021 |
| 3 | 01/25/2010 | 02/22/2021 |
| 4 | now | now |

```
my code:
sample= {'login':'min', 'logout':'max'}
final= df.groupby(['id'], sort=True).agg(sample)
```

Is anything wrong with my approach or a better way in python to solve this problem? or Are there other smart ways to avoid strings other than replacing the strings from the df? (I hail from sql,so still getting used to pythonic stuffs :) ) thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's because `'now' > '03/23/2021'` as far as string comparison goes. You can try replace `now` with a smaller string:

```
tmp_now = '000000'
(df.replace('now',tmp_now)
   .groupby(['id'], sort=True).agg(sample)
   .replace(tmp_now,'now')
)
```

Output:

```
         login      logout
id                        
1   01/10/2018  03/23/2021
2   04/05/1990  03/22/2021
3   01/25/2010  02/22/2021
4          now         now
```

Comment: thanks for the heads up Quang. But is there anyother way than handling this without a string replace? like a way to ignore strings while doing the date computation or something